# Virtualbox support 64bit images

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, 64-bit

After I've updated Oracle VirtualBox, I can't create anymore any 64-bit machine of Windows. Is it official? How is it still possible to create a 64-bit machine using VirtualBox?

Also, I'm getting this error upon machine start-up:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.
```

Is this problem still solvable?

Comment: The error is clear.  Your hardware doesn't support you running a 64-bit guest OS VM on a 32-bit host OS

Comment: How can I fix this for me to be able to run 64-bit guest OS VMs? I am using a 64-bit host OS.

Comment: If available, enable your hardware VM acceleration (usually via BIOS). -- if your system supports it.